How to convert Arabic POS, NER, and Stemmed Text to RDF Triples for Ontology Creation
I have gathered a data set of 5,000 Arabic articles from a website and have preprocessed it by removing stop words, stemming and extracting POS (Part-of-Speech) and NER (Named Entity Recognition) tags. Now, every article has three columns for POS tags, NER tags, and the stemming/preprocessing of text.
I want to know how to model the processed data into RDF (Resource Description Framework) triples. My target is to use this structured information for building an ontology in Arabic.
How can I automate the conversion of POS tags, NER tags, and stemmed text to RDF triples?
Are there libraries or frameworks suitable for this task, particularly for Arabic text?
How can I ensure the RDF triples preserve the semantic meaning and context of the original articles?
Will the Arabic ontology creation be efficient enough using POS, NER, and stemmed text as the approaches or tools to convert them into RDF triples? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Example Data: Wi are original words
Date     Text                 Text_Preprocessed     Ner                      POS
-/-/-    w1 w2 w3 w4 w5       w1 w3 w4              B-Loc, I-Pers, ...       Noun, Verb, Adj...

I am considering writing a script or using a model, as manual conversion is time-consuming.

extracting semantically meaningful triples from text is non-trivial. There are plenty of tools and research approaches. What I can say is that you would at least needs some dependency parse tree, and then you'd need rules to map parts of the tree to triples. Even then you still have to map it to your target ontology, i.e. the properties and classes that make up the schema

I'd more start with existing tools like from Stanford people or spacy to extract "triplets" - though I have to admit that I don't know how good Arabic is being supported. At least those two mentioned tools do support that language. The other option would be to simply ask an LLM, those work amazingly good

Thanks UninformedUser for the comment, i did try stanford nlp(java jars) as well as stanza(stanfordnlp's version for python) arabic language isn't rlly supported when it comes to ner nor semantic trees, found a lot of articles supporting english not arabic, that's my goal in the end, a scientific paper to convert text into RDF in arabic, i did download spacy and planning on exploring more, also planning on asking claude3 opus for some help, but my issue is, i'm not interested in the results as much as i'm interested in the technique, i'll explore more, thanks
